# Meaning of negative axis parameter in sparse matrix functions

Tags: python, scipy

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.max.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.max) the `max` function of a sparse matrix accepts negative values as axis parameter:

> Parameters: axis : {-2, -1, 0, 1, None} optional

Following the links in the documentation to [numpy.amax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) I can find examples for the two positive values `0` and `1`:

```py
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> np.amax(a, axis=0)   # Maxima along the first axis
array([2, 3])
>>> np.amax(a, axis=1)   # Maxima along the second axis
array([1, 3])
```

What is the meaning of the two negative values `-1`and `-2`?

Comment: Just the usual axis identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/sparse/data.py#L206 the function just adds 2 to `axis` values smaller than 0. The idea is that the matrix is always 2D and an axis of `-1` usually refer to the last axis, `-2` to the second to last axis. So adding 2 or taking the last or second to last axis equate to the same thing.